# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic 1 and use $cordovaContacts plugin to get all Contacts. using this method

```
   $scope.getAllContacts = function() {
        $cordovaContacts.find({ filter: '' }).then(function(allContacts) { //omitting parameter to .find() causes all contacts to be returned
            $scope.contacts = allContacts;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(allContacts));
        });
    };
```

but when i run the app i am facing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined
>       at Object.find (http://192.168.15.37:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js:7:23415)
>       at Scope.$scope.getContactList (http://192.168.15.37:8100/js/controllers/home.js:47:30)
>       at fn (eval at compile (http://192.168.15.37:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27638:15), :4:233)
>       at Scope.scope.(anonymous function) [as $onRefresh] (http://192.168.15.37:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53624:20)
>       at start (http://192.168.15.37:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:60495:22)

Comment: where is the `fields`?

Comment: i dont know where is fields

Comment: `fields` is coming from Cordova. Try `.find([])` or `.find({})` instead of `.find({ filter: '' })`.

Comment: @Lex now this error comesup
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Object.find (ng-cordova.min.js:7)

Comment: Can you post an edit to your question? Simply changing the parameters of the call  to `.find()` should not result an the error that you're reporting now.